# ServiceStack Request DTO with multiple parameters

Tags: servicestack

I am am newbie so be kind.
I can call my Web Service which takes 3 parameters, however I only ever see the first parameter in the request

```
[RestService("/GetServiceData/{wOwner}/{wBlockSize}/{wBlock}")]
public class GetServiceData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string wOwner { get; set; }
    public int? wBlockSize { get; set; }
    public int? wBlock { get; set; }

}
```

I try to call from my browser like this: localhost:62577/servicestack/json/syncreply/GetServiceData/?wOwner=bb5456ce-a022-4ab8-8256-281e8b41aac5&ampwBlockSize=1000&ampwBlock=2

But only get wOwner being set in GetServiceData

Same for this javascript

```
var pData = {wOwner:'bb5456ce-a022-4ab8-8256-281e8b41aac5', wBlockSize:1000, wBlock:2};
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:62577/servicestack/json/syncreply/GetServiceData",
  data: pData,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/json",
```

Any clues on what I am missing?

Comment: Can't believe I spent hours trying to sort this out and as soon as I click post I see that wBlockSize and wBlock do not have attribute [DataMember]

Added that and it all works now.

Comment: Next time you'll not forget that :)

Comment: add your own solution as the answer!